# C++ alternate commands for CLS

Tags: c++, linux

Hello I'm using CodeLite on Linux. When I use `system("cls");`, `system("pause>0");` or something like that, I get `sh: 1: cls: not found error`.
I did a search by myself and I realise these commands are for Windows.
Does someone know where can I find the equivalent commands for Linux?

Comment: You are looking for `clear` command of Linux.

Comment: On linux command is "clean".  In any case strongly suggesting to use [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) library instead.

Comment: This is not a C++ question, it is a Linux question. And it already has an answer here. https://askubuntu.com/questions/25077/how-to-really-clear-the-terminal

Comment: @LouisCloete it's a C++ question because he's asking about how to use C++'s `system()` function on Linux. That system invokes console commands while executing a program, so this question will be a C++ and Linux question.

Comment: Yes, but OP does know how to call system. The question was about what the Linux equivalent of Windows' `cls` is. The issue wasn't with a C++ thing.

Answer (score 2):

The `system()` function what does is opening a new console tab with the command you introduce by parameters. So `system("cls")` will open a new console and do the `cls` command. As you said, `cls` is a Windows command, so you need to change it to the equivalent command in Linux: `clear`. So, to make the functions `system("cls")` work on Linux, you should use `system("clear")`.
For the other options you're asking, it's the same, you just need to search for the equivalent commands in Linux.
Finally, it's important to know these kinds of functions aren't very recommendable, cause they made your code work only for a specific SO. You should search for libraries that have functions that do the same and can help make your code portable.